# How to pass php vairables to a fopen

Tags: php, concatenation, fopen

I'm struggling to use a php function, fopen with multiple variables.

I have two variables: `$language` is the extension ( E.G. .php ) and `$url` is a random number generated at the start of the script.

Here is my code but it always throws the die statement and doesn't work

```
$filename = "tools/scripts/tool".$language."?id=".$url;
$fh = fopen($filename, "w") or die("There Was An Error With The Script.");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fopen will open the files content itself. It doesn't parse the file.

You might use exec() or you can call the file over a webserver.

fopen('http://localhost/yourfile.php?param='.$param);

Not to mention, that you are trying to write to a file there... ,"w")

yourfile.php?param=123 <- is not a valid filename

Comment: I changed the code to:                                                                              $fh = fopen("http://mathswiki.org/submit/tools/scripts/tool.php?id=".$url, "w") fwrite($fh, $page);

Comment: That is an URL, you need to make an HTTP call to fetch the data. `fopen` is for opening files on your hard drive.